# Can a website with a strict crossdomain.xml policy load flash files from other sites?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

If an index.html file on Site1.com that loads a .SWF file that is hosted on Site2.com; and Site1.com has a strict crossdomain.xml file (Shown below), will the swf file on Site2.com fail to display due to the crossdomain policy? My initial thought is NO but I would like to know for sure, thanks.

The crossdomain.xml on Site1.com:
`<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.Site1.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>`

Can www.site1.com serve an index.html that includes a swf file from www.site2.com and have it execute?

Comment: Short answer: Yes it will execute. That `<allow-access-from domain="*.Site1.com"/>` only affects things if SWF (at site2.com) tries to load content from site1.com (ie: sound, video & image files are usual protected types of content). The only other way a SWF might not work is if you are mixing server types. For example a fail might happen if you have site1 as **https://** but then try to load SWF from **http://** location

Comment: Thanks, youre right.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent your `.SWF` from running when served from other domains? or...?

Comment: I wanted to make sure that content from my CDN could display on my web host since I didn't add the CDN address to my crossdomain.xml.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by VC.One, it will execute. Tested myself and it's true.